# Vs 2005 remote debugging

Tags: visual-studio-2005, remote-debugging

i am unable to connect to  visual studio remote debugger when it is running as windows service

I am getting this error

"Unable to connect to the Microsoft Remote Debugging Monitor named 'MyUsername@192.168.99.61' Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password"

but when i run the remote debugger through startup menu it work fine.

how to fix this?

Abdul khaliq

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to connect to "MyUsername", by default, services run under "localservice". Check which user your service is running as.

Also, remote debugging requires that both the local and remote users have admin priviledges on both computers. the "localservice" user probably won't have the required permissions.

Comment: also try running remote debugging service with same username and password on the local and remote PC with admin privileges.